# Providing read access to IAM role to prod eks cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I have an IAM role in AWS with policies :
EKS Describe
EKS List

Now I want that role to access the cluster with only read only accesses.
Is there any specific role/rolebinding that kuberenetes offer that I could use here within of aws-auth configmap.

Kindly guide. If in case there is some other approach too to grant such access.

Comment: Hi, I think that you will find this article interesting https://echorand.me/posts/user-management-aws-eks-cluster/ basically I think that you should use the `system:basic-user` cluster role for the read-only users.

Comment: @Jaime S  Will the system:basic-user role be assigned to IAM role in aws_auth.tf